$z=?$ such that $Re(Z)=Im(Z)$ where $Z=(z-p)/(z-q)$
The problem states : Let $p,q$ be distinct real numbers ($p,q\neq$0) and $z$ a complex number such that $Re(Z)=Im(Z)$ where $Z=(z-p)/(z-q)$ . $z=?$

This is the approach I took to solve this problem :
Let $z=a+bi$ , $a,b$ $\in$ $\mathbb {R}$ .
With this notation we have $Z=$ $\frac{a^2 +b^2 -aq - ap + pq +pbi -bqi}{(a-q)^2+b^2}$ (This is after multiplying the fraction with the conjugate of the denominator , in order to get a real denominator in the new fraction).$Re(z)=Im(z) \iff a^2 + b^2 -aq - ap = pq = pb - bq$.
Moving all the terms to the left side , we have a quadratic equation in $a$ : $a^2-a(p+q)+b^2+pq+b(q-p)=0$.$\Delta=f(b)=-4b^2+4b(p-q)+(p-q)^2 \geq 0$.
Since the sign of the quadratic term of $f(b)$ is negative , the function takes positive values in between the roots of the function. After computing the roots we get that $\Delta\geq 0 \iff b \in [\frac{(p-q)(1-\sqrt2)}{2}; \frac{(p-q)(1+\sqrt2)}{2}]$,so after returning to the quadratic equation in $a$ , we get that $(a,b)=(\frac{p+q \pm\sqrt{f(b)}}{2},b)$ , where $b$ can be any real number in the aforementioned interval .
I am looking forward to feedback (especially if I messed something up) and to seeing some other (possibly more elgant) solutions :)

I'm not sure how much you know about Mobius transformations. I would think that is the way to go. You want to find the image of the line $X=Y$ under the transformation $Z\mapsto z=\frac{Zq-p}{Z-1}$ and this will be (I've not checked) the circle through the points $(p,0)$, $(q,0)$ cutting the real axis at $\pm\frac{\pi}{4}$.

(ctd) which matches, I think, what you are saying: I see the $\frac{p-q}{2}$ as the real part of the centre, and the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for the 45 degree angle.
